# How to edit specific binary data in C without deleting/overwriting the whole file?

Tags: c, file, persistent

I'm working on a project that communicates with JavaScript and C through an embedded device. My goal is to save and retrieve data on .BIN file created by fOpen()

However, when I try to run my code, the stored data are being deleted and then appended with new data. Please see my code below: (Note: kindly disregard the unnecessary variables)

```
typedef struct datarec
{
  char name[50];
  char age[50];
  char salary [50];
  char position[50];
  char department[50];
}REC;

//Post the data on .BIN file
static int32 MODDECL fileDataSet(HANDLE* pCPU, void* pbase)
{
//This part just determines what variable from data struct will be updated
  char *fileName = vplStringGet(pCPU, data->fileName);
  char *GrpName = vplStringGet(pCPU, data->GrpName);
  char *IDName = vplStringGet(pCPU, data->IDName);
  char *newValue = vplStringGet(pCPU, data->newValue);

  FILE *f;
  REC r;
  f = fopen(fileName, "wb");

  if (f != NULL)
  {
    if (strcmp(IDName, "name") == 0)
    {
      strcpy(r.name, newValue);
      fwrite(&r,sizeof(r),1,f);
      fflush(stdin);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "age") == 0)
    {
      strcpy(r.age, newValue);
      fwrite(&r,sizeof(r),1,f);
      fflush(stdin);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "salary") == 0)
    {
      strcpy(r.salary, newValue);
      fwrite(&r,sizeof(r),1,f);
      fflush(stdin);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "position") == 0)
    {
      strcpy(r.position, newValue);
      fwrite(&r,sizeof(r),1,f);
      fflush(stdin);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "department") == 0)
    {
      strcpy(r.department, newValue);
      fwrite(&r,sizeof(r),1,f);
      fflush(stdin);
    }
    else
    {
      //Wrong ID
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //file not opened
  }
  fclose(f);
}

//This requests for the data stored at .BIN file and sends it to the device
static int32 MODDECL fileDataGet(HANDLE* pCPU, void* pbase)
{

  char strBuf[BUF_STRING_SIZE_VPL];
  char *fileName = vplStringGet(pCPU, data->fileName);
  char *GrpName = vplStringGet(pCPU, data->GrpName);
  char *IDName = vplStringGet(pCPU, data->IDName);

  FILE *f;
  REC r;
  f = fopen(fileName, "rb");
  if (f != NULL)
  {
    fread(&r,sizeof(r),1,f);
    if (strcmp(IDName, "name") == 0)
    {
      strncpy(strBuf, r.name, BUF_STRING_SIZE_VPL);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "age") == 0)
    {
      strncpy(strBuf, r.age, BUF_STRING_SIZE_VPL);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "salary") == 0)
    {
      strncpy(strBuf, r.salary, BUF_STRING_SIZE_VPL);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "position") == 0)
    {
      strncpy(strBuf, r.position, BUF_STRING_SIZE_VPL);
    }
    else if (strcmp(IDName, "department") == 0)
    {
      strncpy(strBuf, r.department, BUF_STRING_SIZE_VPL);
    }
    else
    {
      //Wrong ID
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //File not opened
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

What should I do if I want only a specific struct var to be updated? I don't want to delete/append the whole .bin file. I just want to update what I need to update, then access it directly. Thank you

Comment: On an unrelated note, the C specification explicitly says that passing an input-only file stream (like e.g. `stdin`) to `fflush` is *undefined behavior*. Some compiler add it as a non-portable extension, but please don't use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem here is that each call to the `fileDataSet` will create a new and *uninitialized* `REC` structure, where the data in the structure will be *indeterminate* (seemingly random or garbage).

To modify the existing structure in the file, you first need to read the existing data from the file, modify the structure, then rewrite with the new data.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What I've done to solve the issue is to generate two binary files. Before updating the one I use to retrieve the actual data, I copy its contents to second file which acts as a backup. Then after updating the only necessary member of struct, I rewrite it's original contents from the backup file.

Comment: @diegz25 There's really no need for that. Just read from the existing file, modify the structure, and rewrite at the same position.

Comment: "rewrite at the same position", you mean by using fseek? If not, can you provide a simple example? Btw, I created a backup file because everytime I call fopen(fileName, "w") just to update a single struct member, it erases all the existing data.

Comment: Yes that's it. Once you have read the structure, `fseek` from the current position `-sizeof r` bytes.